# Why are React properties not being passed as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Passing props in the app.js is not working while using it in another component (card.js)

Passed props in App.js. But nothing is shown while using it on Card.js

```
export default function Card(props) {
  
  console.log(props);
  
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img className="card--image" src={`../images/${props.img}`}></img>
      <div className="card--stats">
        <img style={{ height: 30 }} className="card--star" src={star}></img>
        <span className="bold">{props.rating}</span>
        <span className="gray bold">({props.reviewCount})</span>
        <span className="gray bold">{props.country}</span>
        <p className="bold">{props.title}</p>
        <p>
          <span className="bold">from ${props.price} per person</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
      <Hero></Hero>
      <Licence test={"Test123"} />
      <Card>
        img="sports1.webp" rating={"5.0"}
        reviewCount={6}
        country="USA"
        title="Life Lessons with Tiger woods"
        price={120}
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Based off that code you're probably getting an error. Have you checked the devtools console (F12) in your browser? For example:  `src={star}`. `star` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: `<Card>...</Card>`   It's `<Card img=""/>`   Your currently passing your props as children..